# getting a cell array of string into a matrix or table Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, cell-array

I'm gathering information from calculations performed on some data and stored into arrays. I also have some info about these data coming from a text file which now and then contains strings.

The strings from the text files got saved into a `{}` cell array of strings such as:

```
strings={'s1' 's2' 's3'};
a=[1 2 3]
```

What the strings and arrays contain is generated based on a few conditionals from the data present in the text file as well as some data I have in matlab through a loop doing things like that:

```
srings{e}=blablahFromSomewhere{e}
a(e)=otherNumericalBlahBlahFromSomwehre(e+6)
```

Ultimately I want to joint this into a table. I would normally do this:

```
T=[a(:) strings(:)]
```

But I'm facing the following error:

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Can anyone help? I don't really want to transform the strings into integers because the content of the string is handier to have in the output in running the analysis.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
strings={'s1' 's2' 's3'};
a=[1 2 3];
outputfile = 'output.txt';

%%// Code to horziontally concatenate to result in a Nx2 cell array
out = [num2cell(num2str(a,'%d')') strings']

%%// Write to outputfile - Method 1
out = out';
fid = fopen(outputfile,'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\t%s\n', out{:});
fclose(fid);

%%// Write to outputfile - Method 2
%%// Create a text file and clear it out of any content. This is needed, as otherwise
%%// XLSREAD was initializing CSV files with weird characters
%% dlmwrite(outputfile,'');

%%// Write to CSV file using XLSREAD
%xlswrite(outputfile,out)

%%// Verify
type(outputfile)
```

**Output**

```
out = 

    '1'    's1'
    '2'    's2'
    '3'    's3'


1   s1
2   s2
3   s3
```

Comment: Ok THIS is pretty close but then when I use the following ``dlmwrite(fileName,T,'-append','delimiter','\t');`` the string gets split in as many "columns" as there are tabs.

Comment: Edited to your new requirements!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's giving me every character separated by a comma sadly. I also get an error that it could not start Excel. This is turning out to be a headache of a task

Comment: It would appear ``xlswrite`` is a PC only thing. Downloaded the "fix" for mac developed by third party but I will only save in xls which ultimately isn't really handy since this table has to go to R. Damn MATLAB!

Comment: Alright, just edited a version of code that doesn't require XLSREAD. Hope this settles the deal! Let us know!

Comment: Great! Superb! Thanks so much for your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain a char array:

```
    aux = num2str(a(:));
    aux = mat2cell(aux,ones(1,size(aux,1)),size(aux,2));
    T = cell2mat([aux strings(:)]);
```

The result is a 2D char array (leading spaces are introduced if needed):

```
    T =

    1s1
    2s2
    3s3
```

Comment: OP has mentioned - "T=[a(:) strings(:)]", so I think he needs a cell output.

Comment: hey @Luis Thanks. It's not quite what I want. The ultimate table should consist of two columns one for ``a`` and one for ``strings``

Comment: @Bastien So... do you want a 2D-cell array as the result?

Comment: I guess a 2D-cell array could do yeah.

Comment: although dlmwrite might not like it (see my comment to answer below)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you want, but it would seem to be:

```
T = table(a(:), strings(:));
```

Assuming I'm reading the documentation for `table` correctly.

Or, for a cell array:

```
C = [num2cell(a(:)) strings(:)];
```

Comment: Thought this would be perfect but then because I'm using dlmwrite to write to a text file I get the following:
``Error using dlmwrite (line 118)
The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix.``

Comment: @Bastien I've never used it, but according to the docs `dlmwrite` only handles numeric data, not strings. If you have new enough Matlab or the stats toolbox, using tables and `writetable` looks like it might work. [More ideas here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#br2ypq2-1).

Comment: Sadly I don't have write table... I'm just a version under to have that *sadface*